# Can an expansion for visual studio (a dll file) contain a virus?

Tags: visual-studio, virus

I've downloaded a Visual Studio extension DLL, from somewhere on the web, that I suspect may not be clean.

If it's the case and it does contain malicious code, will that code load into Visual Studio and run?

Comment: Absolutely! Anything containing executable code could have malicious code.

Comment: No 100% warranty but useful if you want to check a single file for malicious code: https://www.virustotal.com/

Comment: Althoug an dll isn´t executable in itself, it can be *loaed* by programs. Thus it may cause harm.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the VTC on this was fair, or necessary. If Visual Studio ran extensions in a sandbox process, at a low IL, with a constrained API surface available, it'd be a different story. Yes, the DLL could contain a virus, but the nuance is that the virus wouldn't really be able to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, yes. DLL files contain executable code that (when loaded and called) will run with the privileges of the calling user, and is not restricted to a sandbox inside the VS environment.

There a mechanisms to mitigate the risk though. For example, you should not run Extensions (and Visual Studio itself) with administrative privileges.

Visual Studio itself has some security built into its extension manager:

> To protect your system against extensions that may contain errors or malicious code, you can restrict all per-user extensions to load only when Visual Studio is run under standard user rights.
>   [...]
>   You can disable all per-user extensions for all users by setting this registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ExtensionManager "DisableUserExtensions"=0x00000001.

More here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814429(v=vs.100).aspx

In doubt, don't rely on it but scan the file(s), and check if they have a valid publisher signature.